# Routes in Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes, codeigniter-url

I want to have a clean URL in CodeIgniter based application for User's Profile Information.

Please Take a look at URL formats below.

```
Actual URL : http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/users/profile/user1
```

I'm expecting users to have Personal URL's like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/user1
http://www.mydomain.com/user2
http://www.mydomain.com/user3
```

URL http://www.mydomain.com/user1 should process http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/users/profile/user1 in background execution.

I will be removing index.php from URL using Route library.

Thanks in advance for any sort of help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html.

```
$route['user(:num)'] = "users/profile/user/$1";
```

If you mean you want /*anyusername* to route to the users controller, you would have to put:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "users/profile/$1";
```

At the bottom of routes.php and **every** non user-URL above it. Otherwise every URL would be routed there, obviously. You will need to implement some mechanism in the users-controller to throw 404-errors, since you are routing all requests not catched in the routing rules above.

Comment: Somehow, I have a feeling the users' name can be any arbitrary combination of letters and numbers. (i.e. not `user[0-9]`)

Comment: Your answer is what i have expected, now only one concern here which is - how actual URL (Non userprofile URL) will work or taken care of ? url can be http://www.mydomain.com/contact. Do you mean I have to write down and route each possible URL to overcome this situation ?

Comment: You don't have to route every specific URL, but every /<whatever> section you have. Such as /contact/:any, /start/:any, etc.

Answer (score 1):

IN config/routes.php

add this line

```
$route['user(:num)'] = "users/profile/$1";
```